# 'List' Object is not callable in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

When I am creating one DataFrame having name df and the code is-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'string': list('abcdef'),
                   'int64': list(range(1,7)),
                   'uint8': np.arrange(3,9).astype(u1),
                   'bool1': [True,False,False,True,False,True],
                   'dates': pd.date_range('now',periods=6).values,
                   'category': pd.Series(list("ABCDEF")).astype('category')})
```

When i run this code then it generates an error as

> **'list' object is not callable**

Even all packages related to this already imported.

Comment: I think you have typo, np.arrange should be np.arange

Comment: You probably have `list = ` somewhere in your code.

Comment: I bet you assigned a list object to `list`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just what Burhan and Juanpa said, minus the "probably" and "I bet" - somewhere else in your module (either in the same function or at the module's top-level) you assigned something to the name `list`, shadowing the builtin `list` type.